# Replace many components reference kotlin android

Tags: replace, kotlin, resources, components

I have created an app in kotlin, my very first idea was to avoid creating many activities, instead of doing that, I decided to create many layouts and hide or show them instead of changing between activities.

Late I found I made a mistake coz my code went so large that android couldn´t handle it, so I ended up creating the activities to spare my code among those.

However I decided to copy the code inside the layouts in my new activities, everything worked great but one thing. My code is linked to the activity_main components, instead to the components copied to the new activities (coz I have 2  of each, one in activity_main and one in the new activities).

I started to replace this by deliting two letters of every component and selecting the one that belongs to the new activity, but this will take me like forever.

Example, I had this code in my activity_main:

```
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.url1.com")
    webView2.loadUrl(http://www.url2.com")
    phone.text = "phoneno"
```

I´m deleting "ew" from webView so it allows me to choose the webview located in my activity_new, and then the same for webView2 and again and again with all my components.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*My code is linked to the activity_main components, instead to the components copied to the new activities* that happened because by copy/paste you had in the other activities this:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

change it to:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_other.*
```

Also did you copy/paste `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `onCreate()`? If yes change it too.  
Also in the other activity layouts change `tools:context=".MainActivity"` if it exists

Comment: what a Noob I am!!... ty!!